# How to display buffer in vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, mongoose

Hello I have images saved in mongoose in format buffer and I want to display them to the user in vue.js My problem is, how can node.js send images to vue.js and then display them in the interface?
Thanks for any reply.

```js
router.get("/:id/image", async (req, res) => {
    const inv = await invstor.findById(req.params.id);
    res.end(inv.image);
});
```

This is the code I use in node.js, but I do not know how to display in vue.js?

```js
 this.$http.get(URL + "/image").then(res => {
        this.investorsData = res.imageData;
      });
```

This is the application content from vue.js

Comment: Could you share the output of `console.log(res)` in devtools?

Comment: The output is a real picture, if you have an idea to write otherwise I would like to hear please

Comment: I want to see the output of `console.log(res)` in your devtools. The screen shot is ok. Because I have no idea what's your got from server or `real picture` is.

Comment: Well I may not be specific, what is said devtools I mean browser devtools such as Chrome DevTools.

Comment: I create a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2vc854zh. I hope this help.